# Using Close Privileges on answer that is question or comment?

Tags: discussion, answers

I recently acquired Close vote privileges and from time to time, I may come across a post from an answer by a user that is rather a question or comment instead. I still flag it because I cannot close it. Why don't I have close vote ability in that situation?

I haven't come across this question in GIS SE Meta, I was curious as how to approach it. I probably have a few follow ups, but I'll keep it to the one post/one question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the ability to cast close votes on  **questions**.

There is no concept of "closing an **answer**" on Stack Exchange, so your interaction with answers has not changed. You can flag them, or you can review the answers that other users flagged. The final outcome for answers is deletion.

To directly vote to delete answers, one needs 20,000 reputation (and even then, it only works for answers with negative score). See [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: You can also, as always, cast a downvote on any answer that you think is not useful. Often that will trigger the answerer to improve or delete it, either of which benefits the site.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can only close a question, answers are either there or not. I think you can move answers to comments at [10,000 Moderator Tools.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

Comment: Only diamond-mods can move answers to comments. Reaching 10,000 does not grant any new abilities with regard to answers.